# Eclipse gradle plugin error importing project

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I'm trying to import a gradle project using the eclipse plugin 'buildship'. At the end of the eclipse import throws this error.

```
Synchronize Gradle projects with workspace failed due to an error connecting to the Gradle build.
Could not run build action using Gradle distribution 

'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-bin.zip'.

Could not determine the class-path for class org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.InternalBuildActionAdapter.
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 16: file:/C:/Eclipse Neon/plugins/org.gradle.toolingapi_3.4.0.v20170220163122.jar
Illegal character in path at index 16: file:/C:/Eclipse Neon/plugins/org.gradle.toolingapi_3.4.0.v20170220163122.jar
org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not run build action using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-bin.zip'.
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:55)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:29)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(ResultHandlerAdapter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(BlockingResultHandler.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildActionExecuter.run(DefaultBuildActionExecuter.java:48)
    at com.gradleware.tooling.toolingclient.internal.DefaultToolingClient.executeAndWait(DefaultToolingClient.java:106)
    at com.gradleware.tooling.toolingclient.internal.DefaultBuildActionRequest.executeAndWait(DefaultBuildActionRequest.java:51)
    at com.gradleware.tooling.toolingmodel.repository.internal.DefaultModelRepository$13.get(DefaultModelRepository.java:287)
    at com.gradleware.tooling.toolingmodel.repository.internal.DefaultModelRepository.executeAndWait(DefaultModelRepository.java:355)
    at com.gradleware.tooling.toolingmodel.repository.internal.DefaultModelRepository.access$100(DefaultModelRepository.java:49)
    at com.gradleware.tooling.toolingmodel.repository.internal.DefaultModelRepository$14.call(DefaultModelRepository.java:313)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache$1.load(LocalCache.java:4724)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3522)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2315)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2278)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2193)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3932)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache.get(LocalCache.java:4721)
    at com.gradleware.tooling.toolingmodel.repository.internal.DefaultModelRepository.getFromCache(DefaultModelRepository.java:330)
    at com.gradleware.tooling.toolingmodel.repository.internal.DefaultModelRepository.executeRequest(DefaultModelRepository.java:309)
    at com.gradleware.tooling.toolingmodel.repository.internal.DefaultModelRepository.executeRequest(DefaultModelRepository.java:280)
    at com.gradleware.tooling.toolingmodel.repository.internal.DefaultModelRepository.fetchEclipseGradleProjects(DefaultModelRepository.java:238)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.DefaultModelProvider.fetchEclipseGradleProjects(DefaultModelProvider.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.SynchronizeGradleBuildsJob.fetchEclipseProjects(SynchronizeGradleBuildsJob.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.SynchronizeGradleBuildsJob.synchronizeBuild(SynchronizeGradleBuildsJob.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.SynchronizeGradleBuildsJob.runToolingApiJob(SynchronizeGradleBuildsJob.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.util.progress.ToolingApiJob$1.run(ToolingApiJob.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.util.progress.ToolingApiInvoker.invoke(ToolingApiInvoker.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.util.progress.ToolingApiJob.run(ToolingApiJob.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Could not determine the class-path for class org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.InternalBuildActionAdapter.
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.serialization.ClasspathInferer.find(ClasspathInferer.java:143)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.serialization.ClasspathInferer.getClassPathFor(ClasspathInferer.java:61)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.serialization.ClientSidePayloadClassLoaderRegistry$1.visitClass(ClientSidePayloadClassLoaderRegistry.java:78)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.serialization.WellKnownClassLoaderRegistry$1.visitClass(WellKnownClassLoaderRegistry.java:65)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.serialization.PayloadSerializerObjectOutputStream.writeClassLoader(PayloadSerializerObjectOutputStream.java:63)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.serialization.PayloadSerializerObjectOutputStream.writeClass(PayloadSerializerObjectOutputStream.java:55)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.serialization.PayloadSerializerObjectOutputStream.writeClassDescriptor(PayloadSerializerObjectOutputStream.java:43)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNonProxyDesc(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeClassDesc(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.serialization.PayloadSerializer.serialize(PayloadSerializer.java:45)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ProviderConnection.run(ProviderConnection.java:121)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DefaultConnection.run(DefaultConnection.java:208)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.CancellableConsumerConnection$CancellableActionRunner.run(CancellableConsumerConnection.java:99)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.AbstractConsumerConnection.run(AbstractConsumerConnection.java:62)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildActionExecuter$1.run(DefaultBuildActionExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LazyConsumerActionExecutor.run(LazyConsumerActionExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.CancellableConsumerActionExecutor.run(CancellableConsumerActionExecutor.java:45)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.run(ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.RethrowingErrorsConsumerActionExecutor.run(RethrowingErrorsConsumerActionExecutor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 16: file:/C:/Eclipse Neon/plugins/org.gradle.toolingapi_3.4.0.v20170220163122.jar
    at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:45)
    at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClasspathUtil.getClasspathForClass(ClasspathUtil.java:88)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.serialization.ClasspathInferer.find(ClasspathInferer.java:92)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 16: file:/C:/Eclipse Neon/plugins/org.gradle.toolingapi_3.4.0.v20170220163122.jar
    at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URI.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.toURI(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClasspathUtil.getClasspathForClass(ClasspathUtil.java:74)
    ... 28 more
```

Before importing project on eclipse I execute the 'gradle eclipse' command and everything goes well.

What I could do?

Thanks.

Comment: Try renaming "Eclipse Neon" to "Eclipse_Neon". The error indicates that it does not like the space character

Comment: Thanks! That solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a bug in Gradle up to Version 3.4(?), where spaces within the build path were not allowed
https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1180

Because your build path contains a space because of "Eclipse Neon" it will fail.

Suggestions:

- Either update to the latest version
- or try to prevent the error by moving your eclipse neon installation so the path does not include spaces